# How to copy files from one linux server to other linux server account?

Tags: linux

I like to ask how am I going to copy files from one of my Linux Server Account to other account? If anyone knows how, please help me.

Comment: Through mounting network shares. Search for `mount nfs`. And you can also transfer files through `ssh`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is probably better suited for ServerFault - a Q&A site dedicated to server administration. StackOverflow is for programming. See the help menu at the top of each page to learn which questions are appropriate for this site.

Comment: Presumably you could use `scp`. If you don't have `ssh` you could use `tar` and then maybe CIFS? How do you connect to account 1, how do you connect to account 2? Are they on the same server (or are these different servers)?

Comment: Do you mean from server-to-server or from user_A to user_B? If from user-to-user, you will either need to be root (sudo or su), or user_A will need to have write permission in the destination directory of user_B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the man pages for `scp`. This is a very useful command that I use rather often at my job.

It works easiest if you are logged into the server that has the file you want to transfer (IMO). The syntax is `scp src_file username@remote_host:dst_file`, where the text that comes after the `:` in the second part is the destination path on the other server.

For example, if you have a file called "file.txt" on server1, and you want to put it on server2, you would type:

```
scp file.txt username@server2.name.or.ip:/home/other_username
```

or where ever you want to put the file. I would recommend copying the file first to your home directory on the other server as that minimizes issues with permissions, in my experience.

EDIT: If you want to log into the server that is going to receive the file, you can just swap the first and second arguments to copy from the remote server to the local one.